# Lack of arrows in Markov Chain graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm following this: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/markov-chains-and-queues/structural-properties-of-finite-markov-processes.html

When I try to graph the Markov chain with Graph[proc] I get the correct diagraph, but without the arrows pointing towards the appropriate states. I am literally copying and pasting the code from the above site. I'm using Mathematica 10.2.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: What I mean to say is that the _arrowheads_ are missing, not the connecting edges themselves.

Comment: I guess it's the size of vertex is too large. Try use a smaller parameter like `Graph[proc, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing", VertexSize -> Small]`.

Comment: I looked into the underlying Boxes again, it looks like the expression for graph visualization has changed, ``GraphComputation`NetworkGraphicsBox `` and `DynamicLocation` are no longer used. Maybe the new way will have a better performance.

Comment: @Silvia, both your and the accepted answer worked. Could you elaborate a little bit more on what you mean by the change in the graph visualization?

Comment: I think halmir's answer is great, you can safely forget about what I said above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set PerformanceGoal option to "Quality":

```
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[
   1, {{0, 1/3, 0, 2/3, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1/2, 1/2, 
     0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}];

gr = Graph[proc, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing", 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]